# POST_SUBMIT event on a field into a PRE_SET_DATA event function

Tags: forms, symfony, events

I've got a form:

```
class COTType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'))
            // ...
            ->add('ot');

        $builder->get('ot')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onOTPostSubmit'));
    }
}
```

But I would like to add the `ot` field into the `onPreSetData` function, not into the `buildForm` function. When I do that, the event `POST_SUBMIT` on this field doesn't work anymore.

**How to add a field in the `onPreSetData` that can have a `POST_SUBMIT` event?**

Comment: is EventSubscriberInterface the solution ?